# Knockout template from an external file

Tags: knockout.js

In knockout validation, the messagetemplate gets loaded dynamically even if I did not reference the file, the validation plugin looks for the file and automatically loads it.
So I was wondering does this actually work with knockout templates? or do I have to load them in my code?

Comment: knockout templates are not loaded by default from external files. You have `manually load` them i.e. jquery or other js, implement your `custom component loader` or `require.js`, or `inject` them in your html.

Comment: I ended up using the knockout-amd-helpers, however the template gets loaded but not rendered

Answer (score 0):

You can get template from server, add it to your DOM and call applyBindings to it.

```
ko.applyBindings(yourViewModel, document.getElementById("newTemplateId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We're loading templates the following way:

In the header add refs to single template file or file containing concatenated templates:

```
    <script id="templateId" src="templates/template.html" type="text/html"></script>
    <script src="templates/a_set_of_concatenated_templates.html" type="text/html"></script>
```

Somewhere below resides code loading templates and then create root model and apply bindings:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var promises = $("script[type='text/html']").map(function(_, script) {
            if(script.src) {
                var deffered = $.Deferred(); 
                $.get(script.src, function(tmpl) {
                    script.text = tmpl;
                    if(tmpl.indexOf('type="text/html"') !== -1 || tmpl.indexOf("type='text/html'") !== -1) {
                        $(document.body).append(tmpl);
                    }
                    deffered.resolve();
                })
                return deffered.promise();
            }
        });
        $.when.apply($.when, promises).done(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(createRootModel());
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Note: as you can see from code, we're using jQuery

Comment: Thank you for your help, however the plugin knockout-amd-helpers helped me a lot